# UIKit (GetUIKit) – Slider image not loading until transition

Tags: slider, getuikit

I'm using UIKit (GetUIKit) and I've added a simple slider (https://getuikit.com/docs/slider) but for some reason, the right image isn't loading until the transition happens.

Here's a screen capture of it happening: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y_LV2yE99PA

Here's a fiddle in which I can recreate it: https://jsfiddle.net/kungfauxn00b/s237uh9m/3

Here's my code:

```
<div id="hero-carousel" class="uk-container-expand">
    <div class="uk-position-relative uk-visible-toggle uk-light" uk-slider="center: true; autoplay: true; autoplay-interval: 3000;">
        <ul class="uk-slider-items uk-grid">
            <li class="uk-width-3-4">
                <div class="uk-panel">
                    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/2000x800/333/fff" alt="">
                    <div class="uk-position-center uk-panel">This is some extra text</div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="uk-width-3-4">
                <div class="uk-panel">
                    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/2000x800/333/fff" alt="">
                    <div class="uk-position-center uk-panel"></div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="uk-width-3-4">
                <div class="uk-panel">
                    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/2000x800/333/fff" alt="">
                    <div class="uk-position-center uk-panel"></div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <a class="uk-position-center-left uk-position-small uk-hidden-hover" href="#" uk-slidenav-previous uk-slider-item="previous"></a>
        <a class="uk-position-center-right uk-position-small uk-hidden-hover" href="#" uk-slidenav-next uk-slider-item="next"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Disregard, it's been logged as a bug: https://github.com/uikit/uikit/issues/4087

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the issue. It's actually Bug From Uikit like when you have slider amount width lesser then you container width then it'll not load properly in center mode. Actually it's disable infinite mode. Please refer the respond over the issue from Uikit Author below link. github.com/uikit/uikit/issues/3610 – Nasrullah Bhoraniya just no

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: Ok, I found the issue. It's actually Bug From Uikit like when you have slider amount width lesser then you container width then it'll not load properly in center mode. Actually it's disable infinite mode.

Please refer the respond over the issue from Uikit Author below link.
https://github.com/uikit/uikit/issues/3610

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm we have a sort of fix or hack ... centred slider:
IF only 3 thumbs used .. its a problem

IF 4 or more thumbs / slides added .. it fixes the invisible next slide

See links to fiddles in my reply to Kungfauxn00b here:

https://github.com/uikit/uikit/issues/4087